# failable init in singleton class with private initializer in swift

Tags: ios, swift, static, singleton

I have a class with a shared singleton instance. my class has one private initializer that is failable. when I run my code, my code crashes with nothing but

```
Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x105289b9c)
```

what I'm doing wrong?

```
class MyClass {
    static var shared = MyClass()

    private var a: Int

    private init?() {
        guard someCondition else {
            return nil
        }

        self.a = 0
        self.myFunction()
    }

    private func myFunction() {
        // some code
    }
}
```

Comment: Set an exception breakpoint and see if that helps you identify where the problem is.  One thing; An optional Singleton seems a bit off to me

Comment: it seems a bit weird, but the reason I'm using optical singleton is that this is going to be log module, for my framework and I want to initialize this just by me, not other developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation, the problem was cycling access, in `myFunction` I was creating an object that had a call to `MyClass.shared?.someFunction()`, and it was the reason for the crash.